# How many ways to fill the $N \times N$ board by nonnegative integers, such that sum of the numbers of each row and each column is $R$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, contest-math

How many ways to fill the $4 \times 4$ board by nonnegative integers, such that sum of the numbers of each row and each column is $3$?

I wrote a brute-force and got  $2008$ which seems to be the right answer. I was wondering what is the combinatorial way of solving this one? How about the general problem of $N\times N$ or $N\times K$ with sum a $R$?

Comment: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/Birkhoff/

Comment: @deinst: What do you mean?

Comment: @Fool  The problem you ask (in the NxN case) is counting the number of lattice points in a Birkhoff polytope.  The number is a polynomial in the row/column sum.  They computed this polynomial for N up to 10.

Comment: For a simpler approach see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69000/iterating-over-all-matrices-with-fixed-row-and-column-sums